# sql инъекция, нужна помощь

Tags: javascript, php, sql

Можно ли сделать sql инъекцию к этому запросу? И как, например?
В переменную $text

```
SELECT * FROM `test` WHERE `param` LIKE '%".$text."%' AND `id` != 1
```

Comment: Можно, разрешаем

Comment: «И как, например?» — `$text = "' OR 1=1; --"`

Comment: Спасибо. А как выполнить какой-либо другой запрос? Например UPDATE `test` SET `param` = 1

Comment: В общем случае - никак, базовые методы и в PDO и в mysqli не позволяют выполнять несколько запросов в одной строке.

Comment: @u_mulder позволяют. pdo с mysqlnd + эмуляция подготовленных запросов (а это режим по умолчанию) может. Даже есть константа MYSQL_ATTR_MULTI_STATEMENTS.

Comment: @ЕгорБанин  Имел в виду что в простейшем варианте такого не получится. Да, можно поднакрутить настроек, но мы не видим что там у автора. Может он вообще там строку по `;` разбивает и выполняет запросы.

Comment: @u_mulder в простейшем варианте как раз получается. PDO из коробки выполняет несколько запросов. Попробуйте (я конечно уже попробовал): дефолтный пхп с PDO, два запроса через точку с запятой -- оба выполнятся. Когда-то так было нельзя, а вот потом стало можно.

Comment: Это печально тогда(

Answer (score 1):

В общем случае вы должны поместить в $text такой текст, конкатенация которого в ваш запрос превратит его в новый. Можно поменять условия WHERE, можно выбрать что-то из другой таблицы через UNION, можно поставить точку с запятой и дропнуть всю базу.

```
$text = "';update `test` set `param` = 1 where 1;--";
```

```
SELECT * FROM `test` WHERE `param` LIKE '%';update `test` set `param` = 1 where 1;--%' AND `id` != 1
```

Comment: И ещё полезный момент. LIKE-шаблоны надо дополнительно экранировать. Если текст шаблона содержит всякие %, _, то результат может получиться неожиданный.

Comment: Тогда уж не стоит останавливаться на полумерах! Следует делать запросы с параметрами!